# HQL many to many and sort by field

Tags: hql

```
Books:
id
name

Trade:
id

books_trade:
book_id
trade_id
```

how can i query sort of trade table(even those that dont have books traded) by books name?
example:

```
Books:
1, 2
time, a lot

Trade
1, 2, 3, 4, 5

books_trade:
2, 1
1, 2
```

Output: 5 rows 2, 1, 3, 4, 5

how can I manage query of all trades by books names(even those trades, that not in the books_trade table)?

Comment: What did you try? Where is your `HQL` query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

already solved it by query

```
select b FROM Trade t left join t.set s order by s.name DESC/ASC
```

where set-> many-to-many HashSet